# My app quits unexpectedly when using BCR for recognition, error "NoSuchMethodError" is reported

Tags: android, machine-learning, huawei-mobile-services

My e-commerce app has integrated *HUAWEI ML BCR*, but encounters a problem when using *BCR* for recognition. When a user taps the recognition button, the camera is turned on, but then turned off immediately.

An error "**NoSuchMethodError**" is reported:

```
No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lcom/huawei/hms/ml/common/card/bcr/BcrDetectorOptionsParcel; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.huawei.hms.ml.common.card.bcr.BcrDetectorOptionsParcel' appears in ......
at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.card.bcr.MLBcrAnalyzer.asyncAnalyseFrame(MLBcrAnalyer.java:113)
at com.huawei.hms.mlplugin.card.bcr.d.a(DecodeHandler.java:291)
......
```

Comment: To develop the function of _BCR_, how about the recognition effect of this open-source project?

Comment: @Mike-mei Kindly refer to this XDA article: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/huawei-developers/integrating-bank-card-recognition-t4135803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *BCR* SDK version is not the latest one ("**2.0.0.300**"). Integrate the latest version. Besides, **the mlsdk.card.bcr** API is currently unsupported. Please use the **mlplugin.card.bcr** API. For details about how to use it, please refer to [Bank Card Recognition Development Procedure](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/ml-bcr-dev-4).

For bank card recognition service, it can input bank card information through video streaming..Bank card identification provides processing plug-ins. You can integrate a bank card recognition plug-in without the need to process camera video stream data, thereby achieving integration of bank card recognition capabilities.